# Chef Server error with nginx

Tags: chef-infra

I cannot connect to my Chef Server (11) from my workstation.

On the chef server, if I run chef-server-ctl restart, everything starts up except nginx and this error comes:

```
timeout: down: nginx: 0s, normally up, want up
```

In the current file for nginx this error is displaying:

```
2015-12-11_13:57:13.15227 nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/var/opt/chef-server/nginx/ca/mychefserver.com.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
```

Anybody know what the problem is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TLS certificates are corrupted. If you specified them yourself, you probably missed a file. If they are internally generated, you might have to delete and rebuild them.